# Mercurial Repo with one sub folder coming from svn repo - possible?

Tags: svn, mercurial

There are several similar questions but i couldnt find any close enough not to warrent a fresh question.

We have a mercurial controlled vs2010 solution comprising 40+ projects.
We also have a contractor working remotely on a portion of one of the projects, a Labview FPGA+RT+DotNetAssembly.

I would ideally like to put his code into "ContractorsSVNRepo" (see below) of our Mercurial repo, and when i want an update i download his svn repo, if im happy with it then commit to our mercurial repo.

I have access to his svn repo for his portion of the project, however he doesnt have access to our Mercurial repo for Security/IP reasons. And since im not that familiar with mercurial i dont even know if its possible to give him access only to only one folder of a repo so this is what i had come up with.

Will this work? can it be done? do i just create an svn repo in the target folder, download it and then only add the files i want in mercurial to our repo? will the two scc systems get in a twist/play well together? I would just try it and see what happens but im not that familiar with mercurial yet and dont want to risk wrecking our mercurial repo and not be able to recover it quickly.

```
OurAppsMercurialRepo
  Proj1  
  Proj2
  Proj3
    Proj3Folder1    
    Proj3Folder2  
    Proj3Folder3
    ContractorsSVNRepo 
  ...  
  Proj40
```

Edit 1:
I dont think i've done this right as Pulling changes from another machine only pulls the .hgsub file, it doesnt pull the svn repo (or from what i can tell, even try as ive not been asked for or added any login details yet).

i did this on my machine:
    HG init ContractorsSVNRepo
    Created .hgsub with "ContractorsSVNRepo = [svn]https://ContractorsRepo.com/svn/trunk" in it
    HG add .hgsub
    svn co https://ContractorsRepo.com/svn/trunk ContractorsSVNRepo
    HG status
    HG commit -m "Subrepositories added"

However, when i pull on another machine all it does it pull the .hgsub file.
the docs linked suggest that doing a pull on the main repo will pull both repos, but its only pulling the mercurial one? am i missing something from these steps?

Edit2:

> Inside OurAppsMercurialRepo:
>   svn co http://svn.contractor.com/svn/proj4other/trunk Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo
>
> Put the following inside .hgsub file directly inside OurAppsMercurialRepo:
>   Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo = [svn]http://svn.contractor.com/svn/proj4other/trunk
>
> From now, when you commit OurAppsMercurialRepo, the revision of the subversion checkout at the time of the commit is stored in mercurial

Thanks for the reply however this didnt change anything im afraid, it still doesnt download/update the svn source on pulling the main repo and i now get an error with my path name
    "Abort: path contains illegal component: ".
I suspect this is because our path names have "**.**" in them so im going to give up and create a seperate svn repo and copy the files i want into mercurial manually. it wont fail, it wont cause other developers a headache and i dont waste any more time on this.

Comment: You can clone your mercurial repo in a separate place, and experiment it with svn subprepos. This way you need not afraid about the wrecks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Possible. See mercurial Subrepos ->
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

Comment: See also my guide here: http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#subversion-subrepositories

Comment: one quick addition to this, Since the other repo is a contractors repo and they wont keep this repo going for ever after thier work is completed, is it easy to detach thier repo and convert the sub repo into a normal folder within the original main mercurial repo?

do i just take a copy, remove the subrepo and re-add normally or is there a special procedure for this?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that subrepos is now quite usable :) I hadn't checked on it / tried it for quite a while.

Comment: semi usable, seems there is some black magic involved in getting this work as the links suggest.
But thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `OurAppsMercurialRepo`:

```
svn co http://svn.contractor.com/svn/proj4other/trunk Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo
```

Put the following inside `.hgsub` file directly inside `OurAppsMercurialRepo`:

```
Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo = [svn]http://svn.contractor.com/svn/proj4other/trunk
```

From now, when you commit `OurAppsMercurialRepo`, the revision of the subversion checkout at the time of the commit is stored in mercurial. E.g. your locally used `ContractorsSVNRepo` is *not*  forced to be their latest.

If you fear that they remove the subversion repository after some time, you can first make a cron/scheduled task that pull->convert the svn repo every night/hour/5 minutes. The magic point here is [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) that can convert a Subversion repository in a mercurial one **and** keep the mapping inbetween. Then you use the mercurial repository as a subrepo as above:

After installing HgSubversion, convert the subversion repository to a mercurial one:

```
hg clone -U http://svn.contractor.com/svn/proj4other proj4otherconverted
```

(I removed the `trunk` part at the end as HgSubversion can also convert branches and tags)

Then schedule this command inside the `proj4otherconverted` directory:

```
hg pull
```

Inside `OurAppsMercurialRepo` make directory `Proj3` then:

```
hg clone http://hg.yourcompany.com/hg/proj4otherconverted Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo
```

Put the following inside `.hgsub` file directly inside `OurAppsMercurialRepo`:

```
Proj3/ContractorsSVNRepo = http://hg.yourcompany.com/hg/proj4otherconverted
```

Comment: @Matma: did you try the second part of the answer? It might solve your problem. And bring history/traceability of your contractors.

Comment: no, i looked at it and decided i didnt want to have to do this on all dev machines. too much work for too little payoff. in the end i just created the svn repo inside a folder in the mercurial structure, checked it out, added the files to the mercurial repo and commit/push. job done. simpler and the other devs need not worry about anything but a regular pull. it means ill have to co the svn repo when the contractor makes changes but thats no biggy and i can control what ends up in our source tree.